Keep the vertical Scrollbar to be fixed in lightning datatable
<div class="slds-var-p-around_small" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;height:300px;margin-top:50px;">
    <template if:true={data}>
        <c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type
            key-field="Id"
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            onvalueselect={handleSelection}
            draft-values={draftValues}
            oncellchange={handleCellChange}
            onsave={handleSave}
            oncancel={handleCancel}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            errors={errors}
            min-column-width="170"
            hide-checkbox-column
            suppress-bottom-bar=true>
        </c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type>
    </template>
</div>

In this lightning datatable code make the vertical scroll bar to be static independent of horizontal scrollbar. Basically i have 18 columns to display in the table. In the horizontal scrollbar when i use to drag then only it will show the vertical scrollbar instead of that keep it in the fixed position of the page. its hard to drag the horizontal scrollbat to end of the page. instead keep the vertical scrollbar to be static.

